# How can I set the value of the ID parameter in Compliance API POST :internal_port/send?

Tags: compliance

How can I set the value of the ID parameter?

Hi, I need help. I'm new to Stellar and I'm creating an anchor. When I execute a payment using the bridge and compliance server, I get the following message:

Error response from compliance server
"code": "missing_parameter",
   "message": "Required parameter is missing.",
   "data": {
     "name": "id"
   }

the documentation says that the ID of the payment / transaction. I had thought that was the squence of the transaction, is this correct?

The version of the compliance server is compliance-v0.0.31-windows-amd64.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Check the [Compliance README](https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/compliance/README.md#post-internal_portsend):

> `id`  *required*  ID of the payment/transaction. In case of pending response or errors, you should resubmit the request with the same id value.

This should be an unique ID identifying your payment.

Comment: Ok there is something missing. I followed the instructions at https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/anchor/4-compliance-server.html
in the Try It Out section (specifically the example the request.post)

As you can see the ID parameter does not exist, but in compliance readme it says that the ID is mandatory. Therefore one contradicts the other.
Then the question is who says the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok there is something missing. I followed the instructions at stellar.org/developers/guides/anchor/4-compliance-server.html in the Try It Out section (specifically the example the request.post) As you can see the ID parameter does not exist, but in compliance readme it says that the ID is mandatory. Therefore one contradicts the other. Then the question is who says the right thing?